# Jquery Slide Animation Behavior

Tags: jquery, slide

I'm working on a simple slide out tab.

This script causes a div - '#slideout' to slide in when the mouse is over '#tabFeature1', and slide out on mouseout.

All is working except for an unwanted side effect. If effect stacks - so each mouseover/mouseout is stacked. For instance, if the user moves the mouse in and out 10 times quickly, then stops moveing the mouse, the animation will continue to itterate - in and out, 10 times. The disired effect is that the animation would not stack. Please let me know if that makes sense.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabFeature1').mouseover(function () {
            $('#slideout').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        });

    $('#tabFeature1').mouseout(function () {
            $('#slideout').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior as the mouse events will always queue up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the animation is still in progress with `.is(':animated')`, and apply the animation if the previous one is completed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabFeature1').mouseover(function () {
            if (!$('#slideout').is(':animated')) {
                $('#slideout').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
            }
        });

    $('#tabFeature1').mouseout(function () {
            if (!$('#slideout').is(':animated')) {
                $('#slideout').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: This ended up being the ultimate solution to for me. This is a simple slide out panel.

    $('#tabFeature1').mouseover(function () {
            $('#slideout').stop().animate({left:'100px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
        });
        $('#tabFeature1').mouseout(function () {
            $('#slideout').stop().animate({left:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
        });